# Does there exist a simple solution to the following eigenvalue problem

Tags: determinant

I am looking for the values of $Z$ for which the determinant of the following $N$-dimensional matrix vanishes:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
N(1-Z)  & N-1  &  N-2 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 1 \\
N-1  &(N-1)(1-Z) & N-2  & \ddots & && & \vdots \\
N-2 & N-2  & (N-2)(1-Z) & \ddots  & \ddots & &  & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots\\
\vdots  & & & \ddots & \ddots  & 3(1-Z)  &  2  & 1\\
\vdots  & && & \ddots & 2  & 2(1-Z)  &  1\\
1 & \cdots &  \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 1-Z  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

From physical considerations I know that all solutions for $Z$ are real and I have also proved that the sum of all solutions equals $N$.
Does there exist a simple way to compute the solutions? I have reasons to believe that the solution is simple, because this was a contest problem.

Comment: shouldn't the bottom right corner have the value $(1-Z)$? Also, how is this an eigenvalue problem? An eigenvalue problem is a problem in which you solve the equation $Ax=\lambda x$...

Comment: Yeah it should be $Z-1$. The problem is equivalent to finding the frequencies of small oscillations of a certain physical system, hence the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $n\times n$ matrix $A$:
\begin{align}
a_{11}&=n;\\ 
a_{1,i}&=a_{1,i-1}-1;\quad a_{i,1}=a_{i-1,1}-1;\quad\forall i=2\dots n; \\
a_{ij}&=a_{i-1,j-1}-1 \quad\forall i,j=2\dots n
\end{align}

and $n\times n$ diagonal matrix $M$: $m_{ij}=0,\quad i\ne j;\quad m_{ii}=a_{ii},\quad i=1\dots n.$

Then the original somewhat strange-looking problem 
\begin{align}
|A-M z| =0
\end{align}
can be transformed easily
into familiar eigenvalue problem, either $|(M^{-1}A)-z I|=0$
or $|(A^{-1}M)-\zeta I|=0,\quad \zeta=\frac{1}{z}$, 
whichever would be simpler to solve.

It looks like matrix $C=A^{-1}M$ is a better candidate, 
since $B=A^{-1}$ has a trivial tridiagonal structure: 
$b_{11}=1$, $2$ for all the rest of diagonal elements,
while all elements above and below main diagonal are $-1$.

The matrix $A^{-1}M$ has also a well-defined tridiagonal structure,
thus $|(A^{-1}M)-\zeta I|=0$ is much simpler to solve than the original system  (***Edit***):

\begin{align}
C_n&=A_n^{-1}M_n=
\left[\begin{matrix} 
n    & -(n-1)  &        &           &          \\
-n   &  2(n-1) & -(n-2) &           &          \\
     &  \cdots & \cdots\quad\cdots      &          &          \\
     &         &  \cdots      & \cdots\quad\cdots        &          \\
     &         & -3     & 2\cdot2 & -1       \\
     &         &        & -2        & 2\cdot1 
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
|C_1-\zeta I_1|&=1-\zeta, \\
|C_2-\zeta I_2|&=2-4 \zeta+\zeta^2, \\
|C_3-\zeta I_3|&=6-18\zeta+9\zeta^2-\zeta^3, \\
|C_4-\zeta I_4|&=24-96\zeta+72\zeta^2-16\zeta^3+\zeta^4, \\
|C_5-\zeta I_5|&=120-600\zeta+600\zeta^2-200\zeta^3+25\zeta^4-\zeta^5.
\end{align}

Thus the eigenvalues of the matrix $C_n$
are the roots $\zeta_1,\dots,\zeta_n$ of the 
[Laguerre polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials)

\begin{align}
n! L_n(\zeta)&= \sum_{m=0}^{n} a_m (-\zeta)^m, \\
a_m&={n\choose m}^2 (n-m)!
\end{align}

Finally, original roots $z_i=1/\zeta_i$,
and indeed, $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i=n$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n z_i&= \frac{a_1}{a_0} = \frac{n^2\cdot (n-1)!}{n!}=n.
\end{align}

Other interesting facts about $z_i$ are:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{z_i}&= a_{n-1} = {n\choose n-1}^2=n^2;\qquad
\prod_{i=1}^n z_i = \frac{1}{a_0} = \frac{1}{n!}.
\end{align}